# How do I make a view that groups nodes by taxonomy term?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, drupal-views

I'm trying to bend views and drupal to my will. So far I've produced a view to display the titles of my nodes. Each node will be assigned exactly one taxonomy term from the set {X, Y and Z}.

So for example, Node A has a title "Car drives into field, thousands don't care". Node A has a taxonomy term "Pointless".

I'd like to group all the node titles by their taxonomy term. So..

Pointless
 - Car drives into field, thousands don't care
 - ....
Next Taxonomy Term
 - .....
 - ......
 - ...

You get the idea. Is it doable and how do I do it? I can't find the group by option in views.

cheers SO.

Comment: To anyone else still looking for a solution: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/group-nodes-by-terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grouping when you use the table row style. Doing that you can group by any field you include in your view.

You could also try out [taxonews](http://drupal.org/project/Taxonews) which could work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

@googletorp's answer is a good one.  You might also pseudo-group by including  the term field and sorting on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Views Grouping Row Limit module, http://drupal.org/project/views_limit_grouping.
In addition, if you want to limit the number of groups, you can apply a patch for that module, http://drupal.org/node/1315888.